# Explain the output when converting Float to integer?

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion

I exactly don't know how why output is coming

```
    float f=1.4, t;
    int d,s;

    d=(int)f;
    printf("d=%d\n",d);
    t=f-d;
    printf("t=%f\n",t);
    t=t*10;
    printf("t=%f\n",t);
    s=(int)t;
    printf("s=%d\n",s);
```

the output is

```
d=1
t=0.400000
t=4.000000
s=3
```

and similarly when  **`f=1.1`**

the output is

```
d=1
t=0.100000
t=1.000000
s=1
```

Is this related to the way the integer and float is stored in the memory or something else ?

Comment: Nooooo, not again! You guys can't google "floating-point arithmetic unexpected result", can you... >.<

Comment: @H2CO3 Please do the honors to google and then Post your answer ... thanks for being so polite :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have initialized f=1.4, not when you do

```
    d=(int)f;
```

You are converting float to integer, and when float is converted to integer, all the number after period "." are truncated. Now d has 1 so

```
    t=f-d;
```

will be 1.4 - 1 = 0.4

```
    t=t*10;
```

t=0.4*10=4 and as t is float so it outputs 4.0000

Float represent trailing zeros at the end

```
    s=(int)t;
```

Here again you are converting float to integer, Now here is tricky part, All the values above are rounded off, here t has value 3.99999976 so when converted to integer it shows 3 as a result

**This is all because when you initialize t=1.4, in actual it is initialized to 1.39999998**

Answer (score 1):

During the first assignment

```
float f=1.4;
```

there is an approximation because 1.4 is intended as double (not float). Something like `1.39999999` is assigned to f.

Try to use

```
float f=1.4f;
```

and it should work as you expect.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that printf first converts to double (since it is a variadic function) and then rounds what it prints, which is why it shows 1.400000

Comment: @ooga printf in this case does nothing. s contains 3 because of the approximation I described.

Comment: but when he prints t (a float) it converts to double before the call and printf rounds.

Comment: @ooga you're right, now I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it step-by-step and see how floating point and `int` interact.

Assume a typical platform where
`float` is [IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32) and
`double` is [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary64#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary64)

```
float f=1.4, t;
// 1.4 isn't exactly representable in FP & takes on the closest `double` value of
// 1.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
// which when assigned to a float becomes 
// 1.39999997615814208984375

int d,s;
d=(int)f;
// d gets the truncated value of 1 and prints 1, no surprise.
printf("d=%d\n",d);

t=f-d;
// t gets the value 0.39999997615814208984375
// A (double) version of t, with the same value is passed to printf()
// This is printed out, rounded to 6 (default) decimal places after the '.' as 
// 0.400000
printf("t=%f\n",t);

t=t*10;
// t is multiplied by exactly 10 and gets the value
// 3.9999997615814208984375
// A (double) version of t, with the same value is passed to printf()
// which prints out, rounded to 6 decimal places after the '.' as 
// 4.00000.
printf("t=%f\n",t);

s=(int)t;
// s gets the truncated value of 3.9999997615814208984375
// which is 3 and prints out 3. - A bit of a surprise.
printf("s=%d\n",s);
```